# Pull struct out of associated type returned by iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, associated-types

I am implementing a double linked list in rust. I have created an iterator that works fine.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct LLCursor<T: Copy> {
    pub cur: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> IntoIterator for List<T>
where
    T: Clone + Copy,
{
    type Item = Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>;
    type IntoIter = LLCursor<T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        LLCursor {
            cur: self.head.clone(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for LLCursor<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    type Item = Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>> {
        match self.cur.clone() {
            Some(node) => {
                self.cur = node.borrow().next.clone();
                Some(node)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make a function that can access the contents of the Nodes of the linked list as it is iterated over. Something like this:

```
pub fn print(self)
where
    List<T>: IntoIterator,
    <List<T> as IntoIterator>::Item: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    for i in self {
        println!("{:?}", Some(i.borrow().clone().item));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `borrow` found for associated type `<List<T> as IntoIterator>::Item` in the current scope
   --> src/list.rs:90:51
    |
90  |             println!("{:?}", i.borrow().clone().item);
    |                                ^^^^^^ method not found in `<List<T> as IntoIterator>::Item`
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
    = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
            `use std::borrow::Borrow;`
```

I understand that `i` in this context is of type `<List<T> as IntoIterator>::Item`. I am new to rust so I do not see how it is useful that the iterator returns the associated type in this manner. I would expect `i` to be of type `Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>`. Is there a way that I can pull this out of the associated type so I am able to access the elements of each individual Node?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the iterator code actually requires `T: Copy`, I suggest you remove it since it is obfuscating your problem. Then, since you know `<List<T> as IntoIterator>::Item` is actually `T`, you can use it directly:

```
pub fn print(self) where T: Debug {
    for i in self {
        println!("{:?}", i.borrow().item);
    }
}
```

I also removed the `.clone()` when printing since its unnecessary and avoids the `T: Clone` constraint. See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a593de434b7a38f7be24249d97aee0ad).

---

The reason for the error you got is because constraining that `List<T>: IntoIterator` and `Item: Debug` does not mean that `Item` is a `Rc<RefCell<_>>`. You would need an additional constraint `T: Copy` for it to deduce the correct `IntoIterator` implementation. No other implementations exist as far as your demonstrated code shows, but a non-conflicting implementation *could* in theory exist and the compiler does not make guesses.

As a side note, constraining on the `Self` type (here explicitly as `List<T>`) is pretty uncommon except in traits as you typically know what is needed for `Self` to satisfy those constraints, and its more descriptive to list that directly. (i.e. if `Self` needed to be `Clone`, but you know that `Self` is `Clone` if `T` is `Clone`, you would use `T: Clone` as the constraint).